# Port forwarding not working for ports

Tags: port-forwarding

I have Fiber ISP connection with Static IP connected with my web server. My network model is,

Cloud -> ISP Modem/Router(GPON ONT) -> Switch <- My Web Server

Let's say My ISP static IP, `x.x.x.x`

My Router IP address is, `192.168.1.98`

My Web Server machine IP Address is, `192.168.1.12` and Gateway of Web server is `192.168.1.98`

I set my Port Forwarding settings at My Router as below,

```
Application: Web-Server
Start~End Port:80
Protocol: TCP
To IP Address:192.168.1.12
Start~End Port:80
Enable: Yes
```

1) Ping x.x.x.x from outside, It works.

2) Internet connection works from my web server `192.168.1.12`

But I can't reach my website from the outside world. So I tested my connection using `nmap`. nmap result is,

```
$ nmap -A -T4 x.x.x.x

Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-26 12:00 IST
Warning: x.x.x.x giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (6).
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x
Host is up (0.073s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE       VERSION
23/tcp    filtered telnet
53/tcp    open     tcpwrapped
80/tcp    filtered http
2099/tcp  filtered h2250-annex-g
2323/tcp  filtered 3d-nfsd
3005/tcp  filtered deslogin
9081/tcp  filtered cisco-aqos
33354/tcp filtered unknown
49161/tcp filtered unknown

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 65.91 seconds
```

Why I couldn't access 80 port of my web server? What went wrong here? One more information, When I check time in my GPON ONT Router, it says,

```
current time: 2000-01-01 01:05:07
```

Comment: Did you run the nmap test _from_ the outside world, too? Trying to access/scan your public IP address from within the same LAN doesn't count. (See "hairpinning" for explanation)

Comment: @grawity: Edited question with the nmap result from the outside world.